# Python + SSL + Require SSL IIS option

Tags: python, iis, ssl

I'm trying to solve following problem:

I have IIS on my production server with valid wildcard ssl certificate.
The site binded to both of somedomain.com:80 and somedomain.com:443.

Also, I have Python (2.6.4) application which fetchs data from a site.

I hadn't any problems until I checked the Require SSL IIS option.
After that I got following trouble:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://somedomain.com/api/list')
```

returns 403 error.

Such thing going to be happend with urllib2, httplib2.

But! The most strange thing that:

```
import httplib
con = httplib.HTTPSConnection('somedomain.com')
con.request('GET', '/api/list')
r1 = con.getresponse()
```

It forks fine! It returns correct data with 200 status code.

What can it be?

Of course, browser (Chrome, Epiphany) works fine on development host.